# Xcode IBAction and Outlets

Tags: objective-c

I am using same action for multiple uibuttons. Is it possible to get which button is the sender?

E.g. Button 1 has been tagged with outlet1 and button2 with outlet2 etc,

When these buttons are pressed, it will call the same action but based on what the sender is, I want to add my logic

Comment: you can either get the reference of the button based on its text or based on its tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//BY DEFAULT THERE IS A TAG OF BUTTON WHICH IS 0

```
if(yourButton.tag==0){
//do something
yourButton.tag=1;
}else if(yourButton.tag==1){
//do something
yourButton.tag=0;
}
```

YOU CAN PERFORM DOUBLE ACTION IN SINGLE OUTLET .
THANK YOU